# Printing array's content in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I have this very simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int maxArr(int *arr)
{
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int* i = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    maxArr(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

but instead of printing 0,1,2,3,4,...,9

I'm getting this:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
1809693728
32767
203279940
1
```

Why?

Comment: How many compiler warnings were you ignoring?  If the answer's none, you need to get a better compiler, or find out  how to turn on basic warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in `i`, not `&i`

```
int main()
{
    int* i = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    maxArr(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of iterating through the array, you are iterating through memory addresses starting at `&i`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your initialization of `i` to:

```
int i[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

...and call `maxArray` with just `i`; i.e. `maxArray(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You give the wrong pointer - you get the wrong data (in the best case):

```
maxArr(&i);
```

should be

```
maxArr(i);
```

I wonder how you didn't get a warning for passing `int **` instead of `int *`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

Here i is already pointing to the array's first element.

```
int* i = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
maxArr(&i);
```

i is stored somewhere say memory location xyz, and at xyz you have another memory location stored which is the location of the first element of the array say abc
so when you pass &i, it sends the location of i, i.e. xyz instead of abc.

To correct it change the code to

```
int* i = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
maxArr(i);
```